# how to configure local ejabberd sever with pidgin?

Tags: ejabberd, pidgin

I have installed ejabberd server  locally (localhost:5280), now question is how to configure local ejabberd sever with pidgin ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As usual jabber client, at first run pidgin, enter:

- Protocol - XMPP
- Domain - ejabberd host
- Resource - 5280

username and password of user which you can create in ejabberd admin web page, `http://192.168.0.1:5280/admin`. Input all this data and click add.

Run ejabberd.

Now you can connect with pidgin or other jabber client.